Try to understand a "simple" recurrence relation...
There is this problem from AoPS:
Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $a_{n}$ denote the number of positive integers which can be formed whose digits are chosen from 1,3,4 and the sum of whose digits is equal to $n$. Prove that $a_{2n}$ is a perfect square for every $n$.
The book does give a concise solution, but I could not understand the first part: The solution stated: "it is fairly clear that $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$"
I mean, it should be easy to see as the book does not even bother to give an explanation, but I just could not understand the reason underneath. All I can see is that if some composition has $x$ 4s, $y$ 3s and $z$ 1s, then $n=4x+3y+z$ and the number of distinct arrangements are
$$b_{n}=\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}$$
then we construct $b_{n-1}$ by taking away a 1, $b_{n-3}$ taking away a 3, and $b_{n-4}$ a 4, thus
\begin{align*}
    &b_{n-1}+b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}\\\\
    =&\frac{(x+y+z-1)!}{x!y!(z-1)!}+\frac{(x+y-1+z)!}{x!(y-1)!z!}+\frac{(x-1+y+z)!}{(x-1)!y!z!}\\\\
    =&\frac{z(x+y+z-1)!}{x!y!z!}+\frac{y(x+y+z-1)!}{x!y!z!}+\frac{x(x+y+z-1)!}{x!y!z!}\\\\
    =&\frac{(x+y+z-1)!(x+y+z)}{x!y!z!}=\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}=b_{n}
\end{align*}
But this is just one case to construct such a relation, far from being complete, may not even be relevant.
Is there a straightforward way to prove this recurrence relation?

The key is to proceed by recursion, by starting with a number whose digital sum is either $n-1$, $n-3$, or $n-4$, and then affixing the digit $1$, $3$, or $4$ at the end as appropriate. To make this more explicit, I'll first submit that

$a_1 = 1$: There is only the single number $1$.

$a_2 = 1$: There is only the single number $11$.

$a_3 = 2$: There are both $3$ and $111$.

$a_4 = 4$: There are $4$, $13$, $31$, and $1111$.


From here on out, we can proceed by recursion. For example, we can obtain a sum of $5$ by affixing a $1$, a $3$, or a $4$ to a previously existing number:

We can affix a $1$ to any of the $a_4 = 4$ numbers with a sum of $4$, yielding $41$, $131$, $311$, and $11111$.

We can affix a $3$ to the $a_2 = 1$ number with a sum of $2$, yielding $113$.

We can affix a $4$ to the $a_1 = 1$ number with a sum of $1$, yielding $14$.


Therefore, the total count of numbers with a digital sum of $5$ is $a_5 = a_4+a_2+a_1 = 4+1+1 = 6$. More generally, we can obtain a digital sum of $a_n$ in three different ways:

By affixing a $1$ to any of the $a_{n-1}$ numbers summing to $n-1$.

By affixing a $3$ to any of the $a_{n-3}$ numbers summing to $n-3$.

By affixing a $4$ to any of the $a_{n-4}$ numbers summing to $n-4$.


This gives us $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$. This gives us the sequence
$$
1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 15, 25, 40, 64, 104, 169, \ldots
$$
and indeed, the even-ordered terms are squares, with specifically $a_{2n} = (F_{n+1})^2$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th term of the Fibonacci sequence $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots$. (The odd-ordered terms are just $a_{2n-1} = F_nF_{n+1}$.)

We affixed our digit at the end. We could also have affixed it at the start; this is fine, so long as we only add digits at the start, or only add digits at the end. If we add them in both places, we will double count.
Incidentally, this is not especially different from the answer given by Prem, but it is a bit more fleshed out.

You could also say $a_0 = 1$, by treating the null string $\varepsilon$ as the lone example in that case, but that can get confusing, so I decided to leave that out of the main answer.

Thanks for the glorious details! This is very educational. So it does seem simple enough, after all LOL.

I think you are mostly concerned with $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$
This is just saying that :
we can take Sum $(n-1)$ & then include the Digit $1$
we can take Sum $(n-3)$ & then include the Digit $3$
we can take Sum $(n-4)$ & then include the Digit $4$
Adding these $3$ terms will give the number of ways to generate $n$
